# Different Enum types for a implementing method

Tags: java, oop, structure

Hey I am working on a game and it will be able to spawn chests, items, and food.

I have a interface called ISpawn in package Spawn.

In package Spawn I have a package called chest which handles stuff for chest because' it's a big system.

In package spawn I have food.java and items.java.

ChestHandler, Food, Items are all implementing the interface ISpawn which contains one method:

```
public void spawn(int x, int y);
```

But there's one problem, for the chest & food I need to include a enum type, so it's like this:

```
public void spawn(int x, int y, chestType type) {
    Chest chest = HungerGamesFactory.buildChest(type, x, y, chestCount);
    chests.put(chestCount, chest);
    chestCount++;
}
```

But it's implenting the interface, I can't have chestType for rest of my classes cause I need to use a different enum for them.

I came up with this idea:

```
public void spawn(int x, int y, Enum<?> e) {
    chestType type = (chestType) e;
    Chest chest = HungerGamesFactory.buildChest(type, x, y, chestCount);
    chests.put(chestCount, chest);
    chestCount++;
}
```

Is that a good solution & design? Is there a better way to do this aka cleaner?

Comment: I'm not exactly certain, but I don't think you need to cast `e` to `chestType`. Other than that, it looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not exactly clear from the code that you posted, but I think you should add a generic type parameter to `ISpawn`:

```
public interface ISpawn<T> {
    public void spawn(int x, int y, T type);
}
```

Then your implementations can specify the specific type that is used in the method:

```
public class Chest implements ISpawn<ChestType> {
    @Override
    public void spawn(int x, int y, ChestType type) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Note this means you do not need to cast `type` - it can only be called with a `ChestType` instance.

If you want to restrict the type `T` to be an enum type, you would use `ISpawn<T extends Enum<T>>`.

Comment: Thanks! great idea didnt think of it.